# Flutter: Items disappearing from ListView when toggle filter back and forth and Scrollbar twitching when scrolling

Tags: listview, flutter, filtering, scrollbar

When I tried to imlement simple `ListView` filtering I confronted by two difficulties.

1. When item not satisfied filtering rules I firstly returned `Container` with zero height and this worked, but when I filter one portion of items, then scrolling down, disable filter and scrolling back, earlier filtered items not appear again:

[image: filtering bug]

Then I returned `Container` with 0.0001 height and problem unexpectedly solved:

[image: filtering bug solved]

Why this worked? `Container`s with 0.0001 height are also invisible just as `Container` with zero height.
And there is any better solution?

2. When I filter ones and hundreds the `Scrollbar` twitching when scrolling:

[image: scrollbar twitching]

How to make `Scrollbar` go smooth when filter applied?

[Code in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/98460304a679c00700fb0643d35960b9)

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final items = List.generate(1000, (index) => '$index');
  var filterOptions = List.of(IntType.values);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: buildBody(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Simple filtering'),
          bottom: buildAppBarBottom(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody() {
    return Scrollbar(                       // second question
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = items[index];

          if (filterOptions.any((option) => option.length == item.length)) {
            return ListTile(title: Text(item));
          }

          return Container(height: 0.0001); // first question
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget buildAppBarBottom() {
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          children: IntType.values.map((option) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
              child: FilterChip(
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                selected: filterOptions.contains(option),
                onSelected: (isSelected) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (isSelected) {
                      filterOptions.add(option);
                    } else {
                      filterOptions.remove(option);
                    }
                  });
                },
                label: Text(option.name),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IntType {
  static const IntType ones = const IntType._('Ones', 1);
  static const IntType tens = const IntType._('Tens', 2);
  static const IntType hundreds = const IntType._('Hundreds', 3);

  final String name;
  final int length;

  const IntType._(this.name, this.length);

  static const values = [
    IntType.ones,
    IntType.tens,
    IntType.hundreds,
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, it seems that using the current version resolves the issue. No need to specify the height of the container:

Output:

[image]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.6.1 21G217 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at /Users/username/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (25 hours ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
    • Engine revision 8f2221fbef
    • Dart version 2.18.5
    • DevTools version 2.15.0
```

For the jumping scrollbar, it seems that there is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25652) regarding this. So far the Flutter team are still working on this issue. You may keep an eye on that ticket for future updates.